# Remesh modifier with keyed physics

Tags: modifiers, physics

So I'm trying to morph between three objects: **Object A, Object B, Object C**. Object is a UV sphere while B and C are meshes created from text. The animation is supposed to start from sphere to Object B. So I've applied keyed physics on Object B which starts from the sphere to Object B. The second morph is from object B to C so I've applied keyed physics on C so that as B disappears C appears from C. The issue B is not seen since it immediately starts morphing to C. Changing the lifetime of the particles doesn't work because it also affects the duration of movement from A to C. When I tried to use the timing settings in the keyed panel, it doesn't affect the remesh modifier on the text. Both object B and C have the explode modifier so that text breaks nicely as they morph. Is there any way to add duration to object so that object stays for a while before it starts breaking into C?

particles for B:
**start : 215
stop: 265
lifetime: 100**

particles for C:
**start : 315
stop: 365
lifetime: 100**

Modifiers for B: **Remesh, explode (alive checked)**
Modifiers for C: **Remesh, explode (alive, dead checked)**

Answer (score 1):

So i figured out how to do it. The keyed physics has a checkbox marked **use timing.** Once that is checked to sliders are enabled. Adjusting the time slider sets how long the particles will move. By setting it to a value of around, the particles move for 40 frames leaving 60 frames for the display of the object. So in my situation. I had to set the time for object B and it worked. 
For a more detailed explanation check [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcipVt9J4U8).